# What is the way to embed Google Spreadsheet into GWT page?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-sheets

Google AdWords implements embedding Spreadsheet into one of it's page (see Campaings/ Keywords/ Edit in spreadsheet).
I'd like to make something like this in my GWT application to allow users to edit theirs data using embedded spreadsheet.
I can't find any examples on this. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Google does it is by using a [Google Spreadsheets Gadget](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/topic.py?topic=1360901). The "Examples of Use" link from that page should be enough to get you started. There are many examples, as well as a "Get Your Own Copy" option.

---

It boils down to `iframe` element of the following form:

```
<iframe src="http://spreadsheet/url"></iframe>
```

Most of the "magic" takes place at the Url specified.